# Blazor wasm webcam using SignalR

Tags: c#, .net, azure, signalr, blazor-webassembly

How can I access webcam using blazor and transmit it to API? I searched answer but only I found how to connect to hub by SingalR.

Comment: The answer to questions like this are almost always "yes, it's possible" as there are many different ways to accomplish this. Please review the guidelines on questions that aren't good questions on StackOverflow https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/MixedReality-WebRTC

Comment: You are right @dimiguel, thanks for advice.

Comment: Thanks @Alexan for link.

Comment: @Alexan You can organize the answers to help more forum users in need.